# how to not enter password million of times on unix?

Tags: unix, passwords

What I need is to copy a file from one system to another, only root has rights to put the file to the destination location and only root can read from the source location.
So I do:

1. start PuTTY session on a source machine, enter password
2. sudo bash, again enter password
3. scp /etc/ username@destination:/home/username/file.tmp, enter password again!
4. start PuTTY session on a destination machine, enter password
5. sudo cp file /home/username/file.tmp /etc/, enter password again

Is there a shortcut? Is there a way to insert the password from the clipboard? or just use the same password on every request?

Comment: @lurker, the destination is under /etc which is not writable by everyone

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. Didn't read it clearly.

Comment: If you care to do a little automation, try expect, or ansible.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the server administrator if `key-based authentication` is available - this way you store an ssh-key on your machine and this takes care of authentication which means you don't have to enter your password again and again.